# #if statements in c++ code

Tags: c++, macros

I'm using a 3rd party library, and I'm not compiling their sources, only including the headers from `/usr/include`.

I know that the source code contains a block like the following:

```
#if VAL1 && VAL2
    do something
#else
   do something I dont want to do
#endif
```

I know that `VAL2` is set to `1`, but `VAL1` is set to 0, in a different file included somewhere inside.

What I'm trying to do is define `VAL1` myself, by copying the content of the header which sets `VAL1` to `0`, and setting the value myself.

Is this going to make it so that when the code of the library runs, it will run into the first block? or is it totally static in the compilation time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preprocessor macros are compilation-time things. You usually use them to make sure compiler know how to behave in certain situation. For example when you're using different libraries for different platforms.

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx)

Comment: Got it. I just wanted to make sure, because building the source files of the library is something I wanted to take as a last resort. Thanks dude.

Comment: After edit: but following the logic, it still wouldn't help since the library is already compiled and I would still have to recompile it

Comment: "Compilator" ... ?

Comment: a typo. English is not my first language. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this going to make it so that when the code of the library runs, it will run into the first block? or is it totally static in the compilation time?

the answer is : it is totally static in the compilation time.

If you would like to compile both versions of your code then depending on context where this `if/def` macro is used you could:

```
if (VAL1 && VAL2)
{    do something }
else
{   do something I dont want to do }
```

then assuming `VAL1` and `VAL2` resolves to 1, the code `do something` will compile and execute, but the code `do something I dont want to do` will only compile - but compiler will optimize it out by not including it in resulting executable.

Answer (score 3):

short answer: **no**

Those are **preprocessor directives** which are (as the name indicates) preprocessed before compilation. Once your program is compiled; you cannot change that behavior anymore.

Answer (score 2):

No, this will only affect the header as it is parsed during your next compilation run. It'll have no effect on the compiled part of the library that you're already linking against.

This means it's probably a bad idea. In general you want to keep compiler flags consistent, and that includes macros. We cannot tell whether it'll make a difference here but, unless you're sure, I would stick with the same macro definitions.

If that means you have to recompile the library itself then that's what you'll have to do.

Comment: Probably going to get the sources and compile them, since It's my only real option to get the stuff to work. The code is in a source file, and not a header file, which is my problem.

If it makes a difference, the library is log4cxx and my problem is trying to log stuff in hebrew (and it gets badly encoded and turns into question marks)